# how to remove the items in checkout for Non-US countries in magento 2.3.0?

Tags: checkout-page, magento2.3.0

I am writing custom module. customer have multiple address in checkout.but customer is selected country non-us we need remove the all items from checkout.If customer selected country is US items are showing in checkout. Please observe the below screenshot

http://prntscr.com/mhrimo

please help on this matter.

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: need to delete the items from checkout for shipping country is not US.is there any event is there for change the shipping address or add new address?

Comment: did you check this?

Comment: sorry not understand?what am i check?
i need hint for this functionality